# Как с помощью Stream API вывести все слова по алфавиту и не создавая новый стрим слово которое встречается максимальное кол-во раз

Tags: java

Вот текст в моем файле: "Hello world! Cat is animal. Dog is animal too. Car is not animal."

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            File file = new File("D:/test/file.txt");
            FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file); 
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader); 

            String line;
            while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                Stream.of(line.split("[^A-Za-zА-Яа-я0-9]+"))
                        .map(String::toLowerCase)
                        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()))
                        .entrySet()
                        .stream()
                        .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey())
                        .forEach(System.out::println);

            }

            bufferedReader.close(); // закрываем поток
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

На выходе я получаю строки отсортированные в алфавитном порядке:

> animal=3 car=1 cat=1 dog=1 hello=1 is=3 not=1 too=1 world=1

Но я хочу не создавая отдельный стрим (в моем понимании какой-то промежуточной операцией) вывести еще и строку которая встречается наибольшее количество раз, если их несколько вывести их в алфавитном порядке

```
Stream.of(line.split("[^A-Za-zА-Яа-я0-9]+"))
                        .map(String::toLowerCase)
                        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()))
                        .entrySet()
                        .stream()
                        .sorted(Map.Entry.<String,Long>comparingByValue().reversed().thenComparing(Map.Entry.comparingByKey()))
                        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

> animal=3 is=3 car=1 cat=1 dog=1 hello=1 not=1 too=1 world=1

Вот второй кусок кода с которого я хочу вывести первые 2 строки. Можно ли совместить эти 2 стрима?

Comment: попробуйте `collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), () -> new TreeMap<>(), Collectors.counting()))` вместо Вашего `.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()))`

Comment: Вроде бы ничего не меняется